# Junit test to test primitive data types

Tags: junit, junit4

Is there a way to test if the primitive data type is correct?

For example, int laps = 3; I would like to test that int was used for the variable laps.

Thanks.

Comment: `assertEquals(3, laps)`?

Comment: The compiler already ensures that 3 is an int. This means that compiling the code is your test. You cannot write a meaningful test for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple test you can run to see if you have an int.  To make sure it didn't give false positives I show that it will not be true for a String or a Long.  And instead of a System.out you could use this to validate your variable and then do some action on it that works for your program.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int x=5;
    long y=Long.MAX_VALUE;
    String s = "stringIam";

    if(Integer.class.isInstance(x)) {System.out.println("int x is an instance of Integer");}
    if(Integer.class.isInstance(y)) {System.out.println("long y is an instance of Integer");}
    if(Integer.class.isInstance(s)) {System.out.println("String s instance of Integer");}
}
```

this is the output of console: **int x is an instance of Integer**

the other two tests do not print out since they return false.